# How can I establish a plugin ecosystem using ES6 modules?

Tags: es6-modules

I want to publish a JS library and let anyone develop plugins for the library.
For example, here's a library I publish:

```
// awesome-lib.js
export class Library {
  registerPlugin(plugin) {
    ...
  }
}

export class PluginBase {
  ...
}
```

And a plugin implemented by other developer:

```
// third-party-plugin.js
import {PluginBase} from './awesome-lib';
export default MyPlugin extends PluginBase {
  ...                                                                                                              
}
```

And the end-user's code would be something like this:

```
import {Library} from './awesome-lib';
import MyPlugin from './third-party-plugin';

const lib = new Library();
lib.registerPlugin(new MyPlugin());
```

However, there's a restriction that the end-user needs to deploy the `awesome-lib.js` and `third-party-plugin` in the same directory because the latter imports `PluginBase` from the `awesome-lib.js` in the same directory.

In Node.js, this kind of plugin is easy because its module discovery is managed by npm. But in browsers, things get difficult as its module discovery only relies on relative/absolute paths.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at the same problem.